Using a for loop to create new dataframes with the same code
I have a dataset of county employment by industry in the US. I want to look at employment by county and industry for the 10 unique industries in my dataset, so I'm trying to use a for loop to create 10 new dataframes.
I'm using this code to create individual dataframes, which works fine:
manf<-data %>% 
  filter(Industry == "1013 Manufacturing") %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Area, "Statewide")) %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Area,"MSA"))%>% 
  group_by(Area) %>%
  summarise(`Total Establishments` = sum(`Establishment Count`),
            `Jan Total Employment` = sum(`January Employment`),
            `Feb Total Employment` = sum(`February Employment`),
            `March Total Employment` = sum(`March Employment`),
            `Q1 Change` = sum(`March Total Employment` - `Jan Total Employment`))


but I want to do this 10 ten times, and want to find a more efficient way for future datasets that may have more industries.
I tried using a for loop to do this
mylist<-unique(data$Industry)
mylist2<-list()

for (i in seq_along(mylist)){
  mylist2[[i]]<-data %>% 
    ...
}

with the hope that it would create lists that I could pull into my global environment. but no iteration of that works. I am guessing I can't use a pipe this way.
Edited to add data source: the xlsx of the first table here: https://www.bls.gov/cew/about-data/downloadable-file-layouts/high-level/home.htm
